# Sort data from table numeric first and then string without asc or desc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which consist a column values as

```
45
55
47
AB
56
AC
43
```

and i want to sort as

```
45
55
47
56
43
AB
AC
```

means numeric first and then string and without sort by asc or desc

how to do it please suggest me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *SQL* you could simply use `patindex()` function in `order by` clause

```
order by patindex('%[a-z]%', col), ?;
```

However, `?` your actual col that specify your table data ordering

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
               SELECT '45'  AS Val
               INTO Temp
               UNION ALL SELECT '55'
               UNION ALL SELECT '155'
               UNION ALL SELECT '47'
               UNION ALL SELECT 'AB'
               UNION ALL SELECT '56'
               UNION ALL SELECT 'AC'
               UNION ALL SELECT '43'
               UNION ALL SELECT 'DSE'


               SELECT *
               FROM Temp
               ORDER BY Val
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following query

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(col1 VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(45)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(55)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(47)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('AB')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(56)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('AC')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES(43)

SELECT Col1
FROM @Table
WHERE ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM @Table WHERE ISNUMERIC(col1) = 0 ORDER BY Col1 ASC
```